# Setting up network cards on FreeBSD

Tags: networking, freebsd, ethernet

I just installed FreeBSD 9 on a new laptop and I'm having some trouble getting the network cards to work. Presumably the file representing the cards is in /dev, but where would the configuration files be? In /etc? Any tutorial or guidance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, run `ifconfig` to get a list of all interfaces known to the kernel. In FreeBSD, interfaces are named after the driver module that controls them, so you might see `em0`, `rl0`, or any number of other things.

Once you know the name of the interface, you need a few settings in `/etc/rc.conf`. If you want to use dhcp, it's simple. (I will assume you have an Intel PRO/1000 card, which uses the `em` driver).

```
ifconfig_em0="DHCP"
```

That should be enough to get you on the network. If you use static IP addresses, you'll need something like this, substituting suitable values, instead:

```
ifconfig_em0="inet 192.168.0.34 netmask 255.255.255.0"
defaultrouter="192.168.0.1"
```

You can then either reboot the machine and let the startup process start the network card, or you can run `/etc/rc.d/netif start` to do it immediately.